# LINQ to EF Using a Collection in a Where Clause

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-5

I have a main VendorProfile table and a 1-many VendorHistory table that contains status codes and date stamps. The query below works at retrieving only the latest status (status code and date) for each vendor.  However, the view allows the user to select checkboxes of any of the status codes to filter the view.  So I need to add a where clause that matches ANY of the checkbox StatusSelections.

[Model Diagram](https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=CD5A047338E8C232!1145&authkey=!ABZipFbNNDI14RQ)

```
    public IEnumerable<BrowseStatusModel> BrowseByStatus(int[] StatusSelections)
    {
        IQueryable<BrowseStatusModel> query = _db.VendorProfiles
            .Include("VendorStatusHistory")
            .Include("StatusCodes")
            .Select(s => new BrowseStatusModel
            {
                ProfileID = s.ProfileID,
                Name = s.Name,
                CompanyName = s.CompanyName,
                CompanyDBA = s.CompanyDBA,
                DateCreated = s.DateCreated,
                Status = s.VendorStatusHistories.OrderByDescending(o => o.DateCreated).FirstOrDefault().Id,
                StatusDate = s.VendorStatusHistories.OrderByDescending(o => o.DateCreated).FirstOrDefault().DateCreated
            })
            .OrderBy(x => x.ProfileID);

        foreach (int status in StatusSelections)
        {
            query = query.Where(x => x.Status == status);
        }
        return query;
    }
```

The above foreach loop works but, unfortunately creates AND condition where ALL selections must be true instead of ANY.  I figured I would have to use a where clause with the following in some way but have been unsuccessful at the correct syntax.

```
.AsQueryable().Any();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use contains in the place of that foreach loop

`query = query.Where(x => StatusSelections.Contains(x.Status))`

Comment: Error 4 'int[]' does not contain a definition for 'Contains' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.Queryable.Contains<TSource>(System.Linq.IQueryable<TSource>, TSource)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: make sure you have using System.Linq;

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb352880.aspx either you aren't using System.Linq or you don't have a reference to System.Core.  You can see the example code from the link working on an array.

Comment: yep, i have other usage of contains working on the page. This error is obviously not telling us the true cause.  Turns out the Status cannot be a nullable type int?, which was causing the compiler error.